# Question on [tag:modern-age]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [modern-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-age) tag seems really too broad to me. According to wikipedia and the [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/early-modern/info)  the modern era stretches back from the end of the middle ages to the Second World War. Or more or less from 1500 to 1950 and possibly beyond.

I think we should put some order in the historical tags. 
This said, I think we should do more or less the same as History SE and split it in several tags:

- Early modern age: that is the equivalent of the Renaissance: 1450-1500 to 1750-1800
- Modern age : 1750-1800 to 1940-1950
- and another tag for the actual era since the end of the Second World War. I don't know how we should name the era, maybe just actual era or present era... Most modern era questions fall into this category. Some implied futuristic setting but since our actual era has no clear ending yet, **should we also include the near future in the actual era?**

**Regarding the future**: we already have the [futurology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurology) tag and I think it's good for now. I haven't seen any tags for other future eras. I think it's best to stay vague as it's mostly speculative anyway. People tend to use other tags not related to history when they ask questions about future technologies and I think it's fine.

I also thought about talking of the ancient era and prehistoric tags but there is only one question and it's closed.

Comment: $\heartsuit$ test

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we need fine-grained history tags (and if we do, they will surface anyway). And I guess the vast majority of people coming here would understand "modern-age" as equivalent to "the world we currently live in". And indeed, that's how it seems to be currently used. Thus using it to means something different would only be confusing.